# Change color of caption inside longtabu

Tags: captions, longtable, longtabu

I can make this work just fine with `longtable`, but I would like to use it with `longtabu` for some of its features.

Here's the code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{cc}
\rowcolor[gray]{.5} 
\caption{test}\endlastfoot
foo & bar\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

If I comment out the `rowcolor` line, it works fine but the caption is not properly formatted.

I'm getting the following error `! Misplaced \noalign. \caption ->\noalign`

I tried enclosing it in braces, putting some `\expandafter` around but nothing works. And it's all the more confusing when the `longtabu` documentation says `\caption` should work the same as with `longtable`, since it doesn't work here.

Comment: longtabu redefines `\rowcolor`. It no longer works before \multicolumn (used by \caption). Try `\cellcolor` inside the caption instead.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer it seems to be working if I put it inside indeed. It gave the same error if put outside, and I didn't think of putting it inside. Thanks, if you want to write an answer I'll give you a day, if you don't I'll write one to mark it as solved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

longtabu redefines `\rowcolor`. It no longer works before `\multicolumn` (used by \caption). Try `\cellcolor` inside the `\caption` instead.

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{book}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtabu}{cc}
\caption{\cellcolor{gray}test}\endlastfoot
foo & bar\\
\end{longtabu}
\end{document}
```

Comment: good to know! (+1)